# How to highlight a searched keyword through LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

There is a report page in the community page. there is a search button. upon entering the keyword in the input search box and clicking on search it will search the datatable with the keyword. it will return the rows which ever contains that search result. both the search result and search key we are keeping in js. requirment is we need to highlight the search key in the searched result as well( in the datatable). Is it possible in LWC to implement this requirment.if so could you please suggest.Thanks in advance.

```
var keywords = ["John", "AUS", "JavaScript", "Hockey"];
var sentence = ["My Name is John Smith. My Favourite Subject is JavaScript. I live in US. I like Hockey"];
const matched = [];
for (var index = 0; index < sentence.length; index++) {
   for (var outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < keywords.length; outerIndex++) {
      if (sentence[index].includes(keywords[outerIndex])) {
         matched.push(keywords[outerIndex]);
      }
   }
}
console.log("The matched keywords are==");
console.log(matched);
```

I tried to use the above code. Somehow its returning the keywords('matched' is returning all the matched keywords, its breaking the keyword in a array of alphabets and returning all the alphabets). now I need to add CSS on 'matched' . If anyone has any suggestion how to add CSS on this one. it will be a real help.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can use a function to transform a string using String.replace. This means that you can write code like this:

```
  this.formattedText = this.searchText.replace(
    new RegExp(event.target.value,'ig'),
    (value) => `<b>${value}</b>`
  )
```

(You can replace `<b>` with, for example, a `<span class="highlight">` or whatever).

Here's a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/HCJG2RgmcL1Up0dHlqMZ/src/app.js?p=stories) without any error handling.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Thanks for your quick response. I tried your resolution and in the JSON data I can see the <b> tag as well but its not getting reflected in the HTML, as in my case we are using data table and upon clicking on 'SEARCH' button the data table will return all the data that carries the searched keyword. so we are performing the search result in JS. i tried your solution on our search result. but our search result is not available in the HTML. so i am getting the tags in JSON data but not reflecting in HTML.

Comment: @subhasreekonar I missed that you were using lightning-datatable; it doesn't support formatting out of the box. You would have to extend the lightning-datatable and provide a custom data type to use lightning-formatted-rich-text instead. This is explained in the lightning-datatable documentation.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Thanks for your Kind response. I tried to render the datatable conditionally and passed the searched result in the <lightning-formatted-rich-text> component. currently its just JSON data, but the Highlighting is working. So i guess i will conditionally render the actual standard datatable and a custom html table to show the searched result data by accessing the JSON data. 
Thanks for all your help!
this issue was bugging me for several days.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,I have a JSON response 'result' from JS like below:
[{"Name":"Alexy Portal",
"Title":"New Record <span style="background-color:#FFFF00;">New</span>"}]

I need to put it in table format. I tried to use
 `<template for:each={result} for:item="res">
                <li key={res.Title}> <lightning-formatted-rich-text
                    value={res.Title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text></div> </li></template>`
    to get the Data in HTML so that i can put it in table format. but its not working. Could you please suggest any solution? Thanks in Advance

Comment: @subhasreekonar What do you mean, "not working"?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, "Not working" means its not iterating and no data is getting displayed through HTML